# Do spam filters block emails whose 'from' field's domain is different from SMTP server domain?

Tags: email, smtp, spam-prevention

Consider an email sent from smtp.eumx.net:

```
From: "John William" <john.wm@inter7.jp>
Reply-To: john.wm@inter7.jp
To: foobar@yahoo.com
Cc: peter@gmail.com, mary@gmail.com, ...
```

Note that the header did never mentioned eumx.net at all. Do main-stream spam-filters block this kind of mail, who claim that it is from inter7.jp but sent from eumx.net? If they do, is there any workaround I can do to avoid frequently being filtered? (I don't own the SMTP server) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you set and [SPF record](http://yoast.com/email-reliability/), I think you can pass spam filtering.